# jQuery UI Dialog: clickoutside fired too early

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Why is the clickoutside firing too early?
the dialog is opened and then closed by this event so the user cannot even see the dialog

With the `setTimeout()` enclosed it works.

```
$(".haspopup").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-dialogid");
    var dlg = $("#" + id);
    // reopen dialog
    if ($(this).data("hasDlg")) {
        dlg.dialog("open");
    }

    // init dialog
    else {
        // move caption to dialog's title
        var title = "search and filter";
        if (dlg.find(".title")) {
            title = dlg.find(".title").html();
            dlg.find(".title").remove();
        }

        // add dialog
        dlg.dialog({
            position: {
                my: "left top",
                at: "left top",
                of: $(this)
            },
            width: "auto",
            resizable: false,
            title: title
        });

        $(this).data("hasDlg", true);
        // close dialog after click
        dlg.find(".lt-sort,.lt-search").click(function () {
            dlg.dialog("close");
        });

        // close dialog after click outside
        setTimeout(function () {
            dlg.bind("clickoutside", function () {
                dlg.dialog("close");
            });
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

any hints?

Comment: Can you post your HTML and a jsFiddle?

Comment: As you are using `500` in setTimeout which means `500ms` i.e half second

Comment: without the delay the clickoutside event is triggered too early and is immediately closing the dialog; with the timeout the dialog is shown, but when closing and reopening the dialog the 500ms are over and same effect (immediately closing dialog after reopen it)